# Problems with getSelectedItem() in extended gallery

Tags: android, gallery, adapter, ondraw

I'm having weird issues calling `getSelectedItem()` in my `onDraw()` function in my extended `Gallery` class. For some reason it gives me an `Integer` back when i'm expecting my own object. When i debug and look in the adapter it shows that it's filled with my objects. Any idea why it isn't returning what i expect?

**Edit :** 
It looks like it's returning the index.

**Edit :** 
Go figure, bad code on my part. In my adapter i did the following:

```
@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}
```